# Laravel validation: require any of two field if another field is available

Tags: laravel, validation

I have 4 fields in request id, CID, PID, item_number

where

- either of two is required from id, and CID
- and if CID present either PID or item_number is required
- below is what I my inputs and what I tried for validation

```
"CID":40,
"PID": 1210111037
```

```
'id' => 'required_without:CID|integer',
'CID' => 'required_without:id|integer',
'PID' => 'required_with:CID|integer',
'item_number' => 'required_with:CID|integer',
```

```
'id' => 'required_without:CID|integer',
'CID' => 'required_without:id|integer',
'PID' => 'required_without:item_number|required_with:CID|integer',
'item_number' => 'required_without:PID|required_with:CID|integer',
```

the above both throws an error
**The item_number is required when Customer id is present.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check Validation rule 'required_without_all'

```
'id' => 'required_without:CID|integer',
'CID' => 'required_without:id|integer',
'PID' => 'required_without_all:id,item_number|integer',
'item_number' => 'required_without_all:id,PID|integer'
```

You can also create dynamic rule array.

```
$rules = [
       'id' => 'required_without:CID|integer',
       'CID' => 'required_without:id|integer'
      ];
if($request->CID ?? false){
      if($request->PID || $request->$request->item_number){ // I assume both are exist not will not be undefined.
         $rules['PID'] = 'integer';
         $rules['item_number'] = 'integer';
      }else{
         $rules['PID'] = 'required_with:CID|integer';
         $rules['item_number'] = 'required_with:CID|integer';
      }
}
```

Comment: thanks. This works. So I to change validation message for this manually

Comment: Yes you can change, `$message` array as third param in validation.

Comment: I'll prefer the first solution. cause I created a config file for validation. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check laravel required_if validation rule

```
'id' => 'required_without:CID|integer',
'CID' => 'required_if:id,==,""|integer',
'PID' => 'required_if:CID,!=,""|integer',
'item_number' => 'required_if:PID,==,""|integer'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.